# How to process massive number of images from download URL using EMR

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, emr, amazon-emr

I have a text file with image urls separated with line break for each.

I want to process these massive amount of images by saving to S3 bucket and process them with nodejs.

How is it possible to use EMR to do this if not what would be a better solution?

Comment: Are you trying to iterate over the text file, download the images to S3 and then perform some kind of processing on each of the images, such as creating a thumbnail? How many URLs do you want to process? How often will you be running this? Where does the text file live?

Comment: Yes. It will be one off. The text file live in S3 bucket

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using S3 + Lambda. Depending upon how many images you want to download, of course, and what you need to do with them. You could run a Node process on an EC2 instance (or your local machine even) that reads the text file, fetches each of the images and puts each one on S3. You can create a trigger on S3 so that when any new items are put into a bucket, it calls an AWS Lambda function. The Lambda function can then process the image as you want. The restriction here is that Lambda has a 5 minute maximum execution time, so it depends upon what you really need to do with the image. If the processing takes less than this time, then it should be OK.

This is relatively simple, and fast as it will create as many Lambda instances as needed to cope with the load.

Probably a reasonable idea to model this to cost it out to make sure it fits within your budget: https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/pricing/.